# How do I use a sequential search to find corresponding negative value in array?

Tags: java

What I am attempting to do: For each element in the array, do a sequential search to see if its negative is also in the array.

At the moment, all it's doing is returning the location of the value that the user entered, but I want it  to return the location of the corresponding negative value.

It's not necessary that it's setup the way I have it, as long as I can accomplish the same thing.

Any help is appreciated.
This is what I currently have:

```
public class SequentialSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args){
                     //  0   1   2    3    4    5
        int [] array = {45,  14, 9, -14, -9, 45};
        int key;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number that you are looking for neg value of: ");
        key = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The neg value can be found at position: " + SeqSearch(array, key) + " in array.");
    }
    
    public static int SeqSearch(int[]x, int k){
        int size = x.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                if (x[i] == k){
                   return i;
                }
            }
       return -1;
    }
}'
```

Comment: You can just find `-key`, rather than `key`: `SeqSearch(array, -key)`

Comment: That was a very obvious solution that I didn't see, thank you!